# $.ajax POST returning "status":403,"statusText":"Forbidden" cordova android

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

I am developing Android phonegap application with jquery.mobile-1.4.3.js and cordova.3.5.0.

i am calling $ajax for web service. below is a code snippet.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: LoginData,
        crossDomain:true,
        dataType : 'json',
        timeout: 50000,
        url: 'https://dsp-wasatchtechies.cloud.dreamfactory.com/rest/user/session?app_name=XXXXX',
        success: function(data) {


            console.log(' SESSION' + JSON.stringify(data));

        },
        error: function(data) {

            //ActivityIndicator.hide();
            console.log('ERROR : SESSION' + JSON.stringify(data));
            //ShowAlertMessage('There was an error while SESSION');
        }
    });
```

It was works perfectly but now its responding:

```
  [INFO:CONSOLE(155)] "ERROR SESSION{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":403,"statusText":"Forbidden"}", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js (155)
```

what is wrong this code ? why it is not working ?
any help, suggestion will be appreciated

thank you in advance.

Comment: ERROR : SESSION{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Comment: @MohammedImranN what you want to explain ?

Comment: I dont get any permission error. may be you shoud configure access origin in config.xml as <access origin="*" />

Comment: i already have <access origin="*" />

Comment: probably your device doesn't trust the ssl certificate

Comment: have lot devices i tried with nexus 5, nexus3,samsung S4,Samsung s3, tried everything with no success :(

Comment: it was worked perfectly about month ago. but dont know why now its not working

Answer (score 2):

1. ensure the server code returns a CORS header granting access from other sites:

> eg:  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

2. ensure "ModSecurity" is disabled on your server (if you have cPanel access you should be able to do that via cPanel / Security or something like that)
3. ensure you have the cordova whitelist plugin installed (use the "legacy" plugin for cordova pre v5.0.0):

   $ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-legacy-whitelist
4. setup a very open whitelist in your cordova config.xml:

   <allow-intent href="*" />

   <access origin="*" />
5. setup a Content Security Policy in your index.html:

   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src *; img-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline' ; media-src *;">

This makes everything WIDE open, whereas the point of cross-origin-domains, whitelisted URL request, and content security policies is to restrict cross-domain access.  I'll leave it as an exercise to research and restrict the security down, after you get the thing working.

I hope this helps.

References:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#content-security-policy
https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html
http://content-security-policy.com/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the domain you'r trying access on the allowed domains for your APP? You can set this on comfig.xml.

Comment: sorry but we dont have domain. 
 
it was worked perfectly about month ago. but dont know why now its not working.

Comment: Check this page it may help: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html you need to set the domain end point in the white list i don´t know why it was working before...

Maybe it's a problem on the end point.

Comment: Were you able to find a fix for this?

Comment: Why nobody can answer the solution of this issue? I have having this issue and hitting my head for days. Does anyone have the answer of this issue? Please help us to resolve this. So frustrating ...