# Apache Cordova and Play! framework CORS issue

Tags: angularjs, cordova, playframework

I read that Cordova set in the Headers of its http requests the Origin as coming from "file://" (why?).
So I tested to ask my server running on Play! with some requests like this:

```
 curl -H "Origin: file://" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" --verbose https://claude.wtf/organizers/1
```

and I get as expected a HTTP code 403 (and it seems that nothing can be done in order to avoid this as explained [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/5193)).

**But**, if the same request (`$http.get("https://claude.wtf/organizers/1")`) is made from my Cordova application, it works (HTTP code 200)... I would like to understand why...

**But**, what I would like to understand even more is why the GET HTTP requests work and not the POST requests from the application (I get the same 403 HTTP code than in a curl request).

Finally, as the following request works from curl (I changed the Origin by google.com):

```
curl -H "Origin: http://google.com" -X POST --verbose https://claude.wtf/tracks/create
```

I thought that I could find a hack by modifying the Origin header sent by my application in order to make it work, but the following request also returns a 403 (I think because Cordova refuses to set this header as would do a browser but I don't understand why since it is not a browser...):

```
 var req = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://claude.wtf/tracks/create',
      headers: {
          'Origin': 'http://google.com'
      },
      data: { test: 'test' }
  };
  $http(req)
```

Please note that I have made everything wide open in my Cordova application as explained in the first answer of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28338435/ajax-post-returning-status403-statustextforbidden-cordova-android).